# Updating Database Email Profile for all notifications

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-mail

I am creating an email profile for database email in a script that needs to be run on 200+ instances. The script will create a database email profile to send out alerts from agent jobs. Is there a way to go through all the jobs that exist on an instance and change a parameter so it will use the new email profile I created instead of the email profile its currently using? (added bonus if afterwards i can clean up all the unused email profiles)

```
DECLARE @sb INT;
DECLARE @sc INT;
SET @sb =
(
    SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
);
SET @sc =
(
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, value_in_use)
    FROM sys.configurations
    WHERE name = 'Database Mail XPs'
);
IF (@sb = 1 AND @sc = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating email profile';
    DECLARE @account_id INT;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp @account_name = 'DatabaseServices - SQLMail Account',                      
                                         @display_name = N'XXX - Database Services',                       
                                         @replyto_address = N'noreply@blah.com',                             
                                         @description = N'SQL Server generated email from databases services team', 
                                         @mailserver_name = 'yyy.xxx.pvt',                                  
                                         @email_address = 'ITDatabaseServices@texasmutual.com',
                                         @port = 25,                                                                
                                         @account_id = @account_id OUTPUT;                                          
END
```

Comment: This [answer] (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6015/enable-sql-server-agent-mail-profile/) might help. Please notee you will need to restart the agent for this to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [msdb.dbo.sysjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the `notify_email_operator_id` field specifically. If you can get the ID of the profile after creation, then you likely just need to update the table `sysjobs` references in a single `UPDATE` statement, on each instance you run your script on.

Comment: thank you this is what i was looking for. additionally i ended up finding out i could change the mail out server on all profiles by updating the servername in msdb.dbo.sysmail_server

Comment: @deadLock Great, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

A job doesn't refer to a profile. A job refers to an operator.

The configuration for SQL Server agent refers to a "Mail Profile". In the GUI you configure this by doing "Properties, Alert System" for Agent.

I.e., it isn't clear whether you want to change the Mail Profile for all your Agents or if it is the operator you want to modify.

See J.D. answer as a starting point if it is the Operator you want to want to change.

If it is the Mail Profile, all you have to do is to execute an xp, as in below example:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite 
N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', 
N'DatabaseMailProfile', N'REG_SZ',
N'SQL Server Mail Profile'
```